# Equvivalent of Bookmark in JAXB

Tags: jaxb, moxy, jaxb2, xmlbeans

XmlBeans provides [Bookmark](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/conUsingBookmarksToAnnotateXML.html) functionality to annotate xml for additional processing. Wondering if there is support for such concept in JAXB or an extension to JAXB implementations.

Comment: Your link leads to documentation index

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov - Sorry. Corrected the bookmark link.